# Why is this SQL query on Amazon Athena not pulling the required table from s3 to my database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

What is the problem in my syntax that the query is not running?
(error and error code mentioned below)

1. All the names have been fixed.
2. "foldername3" has only one file and its name is pinmap.csv.
3. There are only 9 columns in the csv file.

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.`pinmap`(
    'circle'       string,
    'region'       string,
    'division'     string,
    'office'       string,
    'pin'             int,
    'office_type'  string,
    'delivery'     string,
    'district'     string,
    'state'        string
    )

    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
      's3://bucketname/foldername3/'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
      'skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

Error code:

> line 1:8: no viable alternative at input 'create external' (service:
>   amazonathena; status code: 400; error code: invalidrequestexception;

Ideally the query should import the csv file from s3 to amazon athena as a table named "pinmap" in the database named "default".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use backticks instead of apostrophes

```sql
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default`.`pinmap`(
    `circle`       string,
    `region`       string,
    `division`     string,
    `office`       string,
    `pin`             int,
    `office_type`  string,
    `delivery`     string,
    `district`     string,
    `state`        string
    )

    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
      's3://bucketname/foldername3/'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
      'skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

Result:

```
Query successful.
```

Also note, that this query only defines meta information about your data in S3, e.g. table schema, database etc, which is then stored in AWS Glue datacatalog. So there is no actual import of csv file, they still remain in S3.